# c# String Query - Getting latest file revision

Tags: c#, database, string, filenames

I am writing a form application where it displays all the PDF files from a directory in a Datagridview. 
Now the files name format is usually **12740-250-B-File Name** (So basically XXXXX-XXX-X-XXXXXXX). 
So the first number is the project number, the second number followed after the dash is the series number- and the letter is the revision of the file.

I would like to have a button when pressed, it will find the files with the same series number (XXXXX-Series No - Revision - XXXXXX) and show me the latest revision which it will be the biggest letter, So between 12763-200-A-HelloWorld and from 12763-200-B-HelloWorld I want the 12763-200-B-HelloWorld to be the result of my query.

This is what I got so far:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"M:\Folder Directory","*.pdf*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("File Name");

    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(files[i]);
        table.Rows.Add(file.Name);

    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Note:
In the end, the files with the latest revision will be inserted in an excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your collection is a list of file names which is the result of Directory.GetFiles(""); The below linq will work. For the below to work you need to be certain of the file format as the splitting is very sensitive to a specific file format.

```
var seriesNumber = "200";
var files = new List<string> { "12763-200-A-HelloWorld", "12763-200-B-HelloWorld" };

var matching = files.Where(x => x.Split('-')[1] == seriesNumber)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Split('-')[2])
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

**Result**:

Matching: "12763-200-B-HelloWorld"

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
string dirPath = @"M:\Folder Directory";
string filePattern = "*.pdf";

DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles(filePattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

Dictionary<string, FileInfo> matchedFiles = new Dictionary<string, FileInfo>();

foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    string filename = file.Name;
    string[] seperatedFilename = filename.Split('-');

    // We are assuming that filenames are consistent
    // As such,
    // the value at seperatedFilename[1] will always be Series No
    // the value at seperatedFilename[2] will always be Revision
    // If this is not the case in every scenario, the following code should expanded to allow other cases
    string seriesNo = seperatedFilename[1];
    string revision = seperatedFilename[2];

    if (matchedFiles.ContainsKey(seriesNo))
    {
        FileInfo matchedFile = matchedFiles[seriesNo];
        string matchedRevision = matchedFile.Name.Split('-')[2];

        // Compare on the char values - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compareordinal?view=netframework-4.7.2
        // If the value is int, then it can be cast to integer for comparison
        if (String.CompareOrdinal(matchedRevision, seriesNo) > 0)
        {
            // This file is higher than the previous
            matchedFiles[seriesNo] = file;
        }
    } else
    {
        // Record does not exist - so its is added by default
        matchedFiles.Add(seriesNo, file);
    }
}

// We have a list of all files which match our criteria
foreach (FileInfo file in matchedFiles.Values)
{
    // TODO : Determine if the directory path is also required for the file
    Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);
}
```

It splits the filename into component parts and compares the revision where the series names match; storing the result in a dictionary for further processing later.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a good situation to use a dictionary in my opinion! You could try the following:

```
        String[] files = new string[5];

        //group of files with the same series number
        files[0] = "12763-200-A-HelloWorld";
        files[1] = "12763-200-X-HelloWorld";
        files[2] = "12763-200-C-HelloWorld";

        //another group of files with the same series number
        files[3] = "12763-203-C-HelloWorld";
        files[4] = "12763-203-Z-HelloWorld";

        //all the discting series numbers, since split will the de second position of every string after the '-'
        var distinctSeriesNumbers = files.Select(f => f.Split('-')[1]).Distinct();
        Dictionary<String, List<String>> filesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<String>>();

         //for each series number, we will try to get all the files and add them to dictionary
        foreach (var serieNumber in distinctSeriesNumbers)
        {
            var filesWithSerieNumber = files.Where(f => f.Split('-')[1] == serieNumber).ToList();
            filesDictionary.Add(serieNumber, filesWithSerieNumber);
        }

        List<String> listOfLatestSeries = new List<string>();

        //here we will go through de dictionary and get the latest file of each series number
        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, List<String>> entry in filesDictionary)
        {
            listOfLatestSeries.Add(entry.Value.OrderByDescending(d => d.Split('-')[2]).First());
        }

        //now we have the file with the last series number in the list 
        MessageBox.Show(listOfLatestSeries[0]); //result : "12763-200-X-HelloWorld"
        MessageBox.Show(listOfLatestSeries[1]); //result : "12763-203-Z-HelloWorld";
```